# Android 12 TextClassifier Timeout

Tags: android, text-classification

Having an inconsistent issue where `TextClassifier.suggestSelection()` and `TextClassifier.classifyText()` timeout after a minute pause.

Called properly on non-main thread. Has only begun to happen after updating to Android 12 (Pixel 3). The implementation here comes from the older section of this reference: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/textclassifier The API seems to have developed substantially, but I don't see where the old method calls have become obsolete or incomplete.

Code to replicate:

```
import static android.content.Context.TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SERVICE;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassification;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassifier;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextSelection;

public class TestTextClassifier {
    TextClassificationManager manager;
    TextClassifier classifier;

    static final String TEXT = "my.email@gmail.com - detect this email address please";

    public TestTextClassifier(Context context) {
        System.out.println("Classifier Test - Init");
        manager = (TextClassificationManager) context.getSystemService(TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SERVICE);
        classifier = manager.getTextClassifier();
    }

    public void test() {
        new Thread(() -> {

            System.out.println("Classifier Test - \""+TEXT+"\" (Length: "+TEXT.length()+")");
            System.out.println("Classifier Test - Suggest Selection");

            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = TEXT.length();

            TextSelection selection = classifier.suggestSelection(TEXT, startIndex, endIndex, null);
            System.out.println("Classifier Test - Selection Returned ("+selection.getSelectionStartIndex()+" - "+selection.getSelectionEndIndex()+")");

            System.out.println("Classifier Test - Classify Selection");
            TextClassification classification = classifier.classifyText(TEXT, selection.getSelectionStartIndex(), selection.getSelectionEndIndex(), null);
            System.out.println("Classifier Test - Classification Returned ("+classification.getText()+")");
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2021-12-06 11:29:16.889 9261-9261/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - Init
2021-12-06 11:29:16.894 9261-9261/com.not.my.package D/androidtc: Initializing SystemTextClassifier, type = System
2021-12-06 11:29:16.898 9261-9842/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - "my.email@gmail.com - detect this email address please" (Length: 53)
2021-12-06 11:29:16.898 9261-9842/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - Suggest Selection
2021-12-06 11:30:16.902 9261-9842/com.not.my.package W/androidtc: Timeout in ResponseReceiver.get(): textselection
2021-12-06 11:30:16.903 9261-9842/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - Selection Returned (0 - 53)
2021-12-06 11:30:16.903 9261-9842/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - Classify Selection
2021-12-06 11:31:16.910 9261-9842/com.not.my.package W/androidtc: Timeout in ResponseReceiver.get(): textclassification
2021-12-06 11:31:16.913 9261-9842/com.not.my.package I/System.out: Classifier Test - Classification Returned (null)
```

Comment: Same issue here, I created a ticket on Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215186916